# Compare two maps using a lambda expression in Java

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

I need to compare the `key` present in `mapA`, `mapB`. If the `key` is present in both the maps (`mapA` and `mapB`), then that particular key and value need to be added to a new map `mapC` using a lambda expression.

My sample code:

```
mapA.forEach((key, value) -> mapC.put(mapB.get(Key), value)));
```

The code above currently does not check whether the `key` is present in `mapA`,`mapB` before adding it to `mapC`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something along the lines:

```
mapA
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(entry -> mapB.containsKey(entry.getKey()))
    .collect(
        Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

If you don't insist on lambdas then you could also do:

```
Map<K, V> mapC = new HashMap<>(mapA);
mapC.keySet().retainAll(mapB.keySet());
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use stream and filter to get the keys which are present on both maps and then iterate over the filtered result set to store it on a third map.

```
    Map<Integer, String> mapA = new HashMap();
    Map<Integer, String> mapB =  new HashMap();
    Map<Integer, String> mapC =  new HashMap();

    mapA.put(1, "Hi");
    mapA.put(2, "Hello");
    mapB.put(1, "Hi");
    mapB.put(3, "Bye");

    mapA.entrySet().stream().filter(x -> mapB.containsKey(x.getKey())).forEach(x -> mapC.put(x.getKey(), x.getValue()));

    System.out.println(mapC); // output will be {1=Hi}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add an `if` condition to check if the key is present in the second map.

```
mapA.forEach((key, value) -> {
    if (mapB.containsKey(key)) {
        mapC.put(mapB.get(key), value));
    }
});
```

But what if the values are different? With what you have said, it seems they will be equal

Here is one more way to do it (assuming it is a `Map<String, String` for demonstration)

```
Set<Map.Entry<String, String>> entrySetMapA = new HashSet<>(mapA.entrySet());
entrySetMapA.retainAll(mapB.entrySet());
entrySetMapA.forEach(entry -> mapC.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
```

Comment: This isn't really the right Java 8 Streams style. Basically you've just replaced the for loop with `forEach` and that's it. See `filter` to check for some predicate and `collect` to gather results in some structure.

Comment: Way too "procedural" in my opinion. Try to take a more functional approach when using lambdas (which is why lambdas were introduced in the first place).